# vim-fugitive automatically gdiff on enter from gstatus

Tags: vim, git-workflow, vim-fugitive

When using vim-fugitive if you issue `:Gstatus` it splits the screen and gives you the would be git commit editor and you can move over different files that have changes and press enter to see them in the other half of the screen. I believe it is like issuing `:Gedit` .

I then need to issue a `:Gdiff` manually to split the editor in half and see the side by side diff of the file to review and or stage it.

**My question is** is there a way to make it automatically go to `:Gdiff` when I press enter, while my cursor is on a file name that has changes.

Basically trying to save some time when going through a large list of files.

Comment: Have you tried `dd` or `D` in the `:Gstatus` window?

Comment: This is the correct answer, where did you find it, did I miss it in :h ?
Is there a difference between `dd` and `D`? by the way that is a odd choice? Just checked and it is in the help file `D` is.  @PeterRincker Would you please make it an answer rather than a comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `D` or `dd` inside the `:Gstatus` window to run `:Gdiff` on the file under the cursor. See `:h :fugitive-:Gstatus` or use `g?` inside the `:Gstatus` window.

For additional help you may wan to look at [Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/), which has some very nice [fugitive.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) series.

- [A complement to command line git](http://vimcasts.org/e/31)
- [Working with the git index](http://vimcasts.org/e/32)
- [Resolving merge conflicts with vimdiff](http://vimcasts.org/e/33)
- [Browsing the git object database](http://vimcasts.org/e/34)
- [Exploring the history of a git repository](http://vimcasts.org/e/35)